# How to replace Add to cart with Out of stock in Prestashop

Tags: prestashop-1.7

I'm using Prestashop and have a problem. In settings I marked that i don't allow to buy product with 0 stock. And right now on product list i see Add to cart button, it doesn't work. On product page i have info that it's out of stock and this part is ok.

Where and how can I change it to have Out of stock also on product list? Because looks like those settings in product preferences doesn't work correctly.

Comment: What's your site url?

Comment: It seems cause of your Theme